# How to launch and compare some information from windows/console programs with python?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

It's been a long time since my last "play" with python, and recently I need to do something with it but I don't remember to much about it, even with libs are needed to import... Could you guys give me a hand?

I will give you an example, its not the exactly comparison that I need, but it will work just like it...

For example, I need to compare some data received from a ping with different packages sizes.

Here is the deal:
I want my program to launch the ping command to 192.168.1.1 with the arguments -l (buffer size) from 0 to, lets say, 100, and compare witch is high, or lower...

Something like this:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -l 1
1ms
ping 192.168.1.1 -l 2
1ms
ping 192.168.1.1 -l 3
2ms
```

and so on, so when it reaches -l 100, it gives me the argument with the higher ping (or lower), something like this:

```
higher ping: 2ms (-l 3)
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subprocess.check_output and parse its output http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output . Per the docs :

> Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

E.g.

```
import subprocess, re
c = subprocess.check_output(["ping","www.google.com"])
t = re.findall('time=(\d+)ms',c) #Or parse something like 'Maximum = 67ms' in the output
max(t)
>>> '67'
```

Comment: how can I do it with non windows processes?

Comment: Use the full path or add it to os.environ http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.environ

Comment: I've managed to work, but my process run continuous, like a ping -t... How can I stop it to use the findall?